# A C++ Job Manager Class

Tags: c++

I've created a `JobManager` class that manages the execution of submitted `Jobs` on periodic intervals. While the `JobManager` is running, the API allows the user to:

- Add or Remove a `Job` to/from the `JobManager`
- Change a `Job`'s interval, function parameter, and function
- Signal a `Job` to run if it is waiting

The testing I have done seems to denote that the class is working correctly. What stands out to you as a bad practice and or an inefficiency here? What potential problems do you see with using this? The `Job` could be used by itself but I haven't implemented the rule of 5 with it.

```
// The Job class
#pragma once
#include <chrono>
#include <any>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

namespace engine {

using job_clock = std::chrono::system_clock;
using job_func = std::function<void(const std::any &, bool)>;
using job_interval = std::chrono::system_clock::duration;
using job_time = std::chrono::system_clock::time_point;

class Job {
public:
    Job(uint32_t job_id, job_func &&func, const job_interval &interval,
        const std::any &param)
        : id(job_id), m_func(func), m_interval(interval), m_param(param),
          m_lock(std::make_shared<std::mutex>()),
          m_cv(std::make_shared<std::condition_variable>())
    {
    }

    void Start(bool now)
    {
        if (!m_thread) {
            m_thread = std::make_unique<std::thread>(
                [this](bool now) { Monitor(now); }, now);
        }
    }

    void Stop()
    {
        if (m_thread) {
            m_quit = true;
            if (m_waiting && m_cv) {
                m_cv->notify_one();
            }
            m_thread->join();
            m_thread = nullptr;
        }
    }

    void SetParam(const std::any &param)
    {
        if (m_thread && m_lock) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(*m_lock);
            m_param = param;
        }
        else {
            m_param = param;
        }
    }

    void SetInterval(job_interval interval)
    {
        if (m_thread && m_lock) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(*m_lock);
            m_interval = interval;
        }
        else {
            m_interval = interval;
        }
    }

    void SetFunc(job_func &&func)
    {
        if (m_thread && m_lock) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(*m_lock);
            m_func = func;
        }
        else {
            m_func = func;
        }
    }

    bool Signal()
    {
        if (m_waiting && m_cv) {
            m_signaled = true;
            m_cv->notify_one();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] bool Active() const
    {
        return m_active;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] bool Waiting() const
    {
        return m_waiting;
    }

    const uint32_t id;

private:
    void Monitor(bool now)
    {
        m_active = true;

        if (now) {
            m_func(m_param, false);
        }

        while (!m_quit) {

            job_time time = job_clock::now() + m_interval;
            {
                if (m_lock && m_cv) {
                    m_waiting = true;
                    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(*m_lock);
                    m_cv->wait_until(lk, time);
                    m_waiting = false;
                }
            }

            if (!m_quit && m_lock) {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(*m_lock);
                m_func(m_param, m_signaled);
                m_signaled = false;
            }
        }

        m_active = false;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<std::mutex> m_lock{nullptr};
    std::shared_ptr<std::condition_variable> m_cv{nullptr};
    std::shared_ptr<std::thread> m_thread{nullptr};
    bool m_active{false};
    bool m_signaled{false};
    bool m_waiting{false};
    bool m_quit{false};

    job_func m_func;
    job_interval m_interval;
    std::any m_param;
};

} // namespace engine
```

```
// The JobManager class
#include <engine/Job.hpp>

namespace engine {

class JobManager final {
public:
    JobManager(std::initializer_list<Job> jobs) : m_jobs(jobs) {}
    JobManager() = default;
    JobManager &operator=(const JobManager &rhs) = delete;
    JobManager(const JobManager &rhs) = delete;
    JobManager &operator=(JobManager &&rhs) = delete;
    JobManager(JobManager &&rhs) = delete;
    ~JobManager()
    {
        Stop();
    }

    void Add(std::initializer_list<Job> jobs)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m_lock);
        for (auto &job : jobs) {
            if (AddJobIfNonExistent(job)) {
                m_jobs.back().Start(false);
            }
        }
    }

    void Add(const Job &job, bool run_now = false)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m_lock);
        if (AddJobIfNonExistent(job)) {
            m_jobs.back().Start(run_now);
        }
    }

    void Remove(uint32_t id)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m_lock);
        auto job = FindJobByID(id);
        if (job != m_jobs.end()) {
            job->Stop();
            m_jobs.erase(job);
        }
    }

    void SetJobParam(uint32_t id, const std::any &param)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m_lock);
        auto job = FindJobByID(id);
        if (job != m_jobs.end()) {
            job->SetParam(param);
        }
    }

    void SetJobInterval(uint32_t id, job_interval interval)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m_lock);
        auto job = FindJobByID(id);
        if (job != m_jobs.end()) {
            job->SetInterval(interval);
        }
    }

    void SetJobFunc(uint32_t id, job_func &&func)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m_lock);
        auto job = FindJobByID(id);
        if (job != m_jobs.end()) {
            job->SetFunc(std::move(func));
        }
    }

    void Signal(uint32_t id)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m_lock);
        auto job = FindJobByID(id);
        if (job != m_jobs.end()) {
            job->Signal();
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m_lock);
        auto StartMonitoringJob = [](Job &job) { job.Start(false); };
        ForEachJob(StartMonitoringJob);
    }

    void Stop()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m_lock);
        auto JoinAndBlock = [](Job &job) { job.Stop(); };
        ForEachJob(JoinAndBlock);
    }

private:
    std::list<Job> m_jobs;
    std::mutex m_lock;

    std::list<Job>::iterator FindJobByID(uint32_t id)
    {
        auto IDMatch = [id](const Job &j) { return j.id == id; };
        return std::find_if(m_jobs.begin(), m_jobs.end(), IDMatch);
    }

    bool AddJobIfNonExistent(const Job &job)
    {
        if (FindJobByID(job.id) == m_jobs.end()) {
            m_jobs.push_back(job);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    void ForEachJob(std::function<void(Job &)> predicate)
    {
        std::for_each(m_jobs.begin(), m_jobs.end(), predicate);
    }
};

} // namespace engine
```

```
#include <spdlog/spdlog.h>
#include <engine/job_manager.hpp>

#define _dbg(f, ...) spdlog::info(f, ##__VA_ARGS__)

uint32_t JOB1_ID = 1;
uint32_t JOB2_ID = 2;

struct Job1Info {
    int integer;
    std::string str;
};

struct Job2Info {
    int some_value;
    bool other_value;
};

void Job1(std::any param, bool signaled)
{
    static int called = 1;
    auto info = std::any_cast<Job1Info>(param);
    _dbg("Job1: signaled={}, called={}, Job1Info({}, {})", signaled, called++,
         info.integer, info.str);
}

void Job2(std::any param, bool signaled)
{
    static int called = 1;
    auto info = std::any_cast<Job2Info>(param);
    _dbg("Job2: signaled={}, called={}, Job2Info({}, {})", signaled, called++,
         info.some_value, info.other_value);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
    using namespace engine;

    Job1Info info1{10, std::string("hello")};
    Job2Info info2{50, false};

    Job job1(JOB1_ID, job_func{Job1}, 5000ms, std::make_any<Job1Info>(info1));
    Job job2(JOB2_ID, job_func{Job2}, 10000ms, std::make_any<Job2Info>(info2));
    JobManager manager({job1, job2});

    _dbg("Start");
    manager.Start();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(20000ms);
    manager.SetJobParam(JOB2_ID, std::make_any<Job2Info>(30, true));
    manager.Remove(JOB1_ID);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(10000ms);
    manager.Add(job1, true);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(20000ms);
    manager.SetJobParam(JOB1_ID, std::make_any<Job1Info>(10, "something"));
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(20000ms);
    manager.Stop();
    _dbg("end");
}
```

```
[2022-06-28 16:43:14.263] [info] Start
[2022-06-28 16:43:19.289] [info] Job1: signaled=false, called=1, Job1Info(10, hello)
[2022-06-28 16:43:24.291] [info] Job2: signaled=false, called=1, Job2Info(50, false)
[2022-06-28 16:43:24.291] [info] Job1: signaled=false, called=2, Job1Info(10, hello)
[2022-06-28 16:43:29.305] [info] Job1: signaled=false, called=3, Job1Info(10, hello)
[2022-06-28 16:43:34.307] [info] Job2: signaled=false, called=2, Job2Info(30, true)
[2022-06-28 16:43:44.305] [info] Job1: signaled=false, called=4, Job1Info(10, hello)
[2022-06-28 16:43:44.318] [info] Job2: signaled=false, called=3, Job2Info(30, true)
[2022-06-28 16:43:49.314] [info] Job1: signaled=false, called=5, Job1Info(10, hello)
[2022-06-28 16:43:54.325] [info] Job2: signaled=false, called=4, Job2Info(30, true)
[2022-06-28 16:43:54.325] [info] Job1: signaled=false, called=6, Job1Info(10, hello)
[2022-06-28 16:43:59.342] [info] Job1: signaled=false, called=7, Job1Info(10, hello)
[2022-06-28 16:44:04.327] [info] Job2: signaled=false, called=5, Job2Info(30, true)
[2022-06-28 16:44:04.358] [info] Job1: signaled=false, called=8, Job1Info(10, something)
[2022-06-28 16:44:09.374] [info] Job1: signaled=false, called=9, Job1Info(10, something)
[2022-06-28 16:44:14.342] [info] Job2: signaled=false, called=6, Job2Info(30, true)
[2022-06-28 16:44:14.388] [info] Job1: signaled=false, called=10, Job1Info(10, something)
[2022-06-28 16:44:19.397] [info] Job1: signaled=false, called=11, Job1Info(10, something)
[2022-06-28 16:44:24.322] [info] end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use of `std::shared_ptr`

In `Job`, you store the lock, condition variable and thread in `std::shared_ptr`s, however that seems unnecessary. Just store those by value. The same goes for `m_thread` in `JobManager`.

Of course, this opens a can of worms, because you expect `Job`s to be copyable, and by having plain `std::thread` and related variables in that class, it is no longer copyable. However, that is actually a good thing. Consider what happens if you copy a `Job`: there is only one `m_thread` running, but now you have two copies of `m_active`, `m_signaled` and so on. Consider doing the following:

```
Job job1(1, ...);
job1.Start();
JobManager manager({job1});
manager.Remove(1);
```

Because `job1` was started before it was added to the `manager`, its `Monitor()` will use a different `m_quit` than when `Stop()` is called via `manager.Remove(1)`, causing a deadlock.

The solution is to not have `std::shared_ptr`s inside `Job`, but instead having `std::shared_ptr<Job>`s passed to and stored inside `JobManager`, so that the code using it looks like:

```
auto job1 = std::make_shared<Job>(JOB1_ID, ...);
auto job2 = std::make_shared<Job>(JOB1_ID, ...);
JobManager manager({job1, job2});
```

Now it is clear up front that jobs are passed as shared pointers, and there are no more surprises. But it is also possible to avoid `std::shared_ptr` altogether, which brings me to:

## Let `JobManager` create `Job`s

I think the intent is that the `JobManager` has full control over the `Job`s it is managing. However, by letting the application create `Job`s itself and pass them to `JobManager`, you open up the chance of misuse. It would be better if `JobManager` itself was creating new `Job`s internally, and never exposing them to the application.

To do this, there have to be some changes in how you add jobs to a `JobManager`. In particular, you want to have an `Add()` function which takes all the parameters the constructor of `Job` would take:

```
class JobManager {
public:
    ...
    void Add(uint32_t job_id, job_func &&func, const job_interval &interval, const std::any &param, bool run_now = false) {
        auto &job = m_jobs.emplace_back(job_id, func, interval, param);
        job.Start(run_now);
    }
    ...
private:
    std::list<Job> m_jobs;
    ...
};
```

Note that `Job` does not have to be copyable in order for it to be stored in a `std::list`.

## Consider removing `param`

The `job_func` takes a `std::any param` as an argument, which allows you to pass arbitrary data to it. However, `std::any` has its issues: it's rather expensive since it allocates memory, and while it has some degree of type safety, it still allows you to pass an incorrect type, and this will only be caught at runtime instead of at compile time.

Instead, if you want to pass extra parameters to the function, consider using a lambda that captures those parameters, so that you can write:

```
void Job1(Job1Info &info, bool signaled) {
    static int called = 1;
    _dbg("Job1: signaled={}, called={}, Job1Info({}, {})",
         signaled, called++, info.integer, info.str);
}
...
Job1Info info1{10, "Hello,"};
JobManager.Add(JOB1_ID, [&](bool signaled){Job1(info1, signaled);}, 5000ms);
```

Of course, if you also want to be able to change the job parameters while a job is running, you still need to do locking, for example by adding a `std::mutex` to the job info struct.

## Improper locking

When you want to pass information between threads using some variables, make sure you always take a lock when reading from or writing to those variables, otherwise you might introduce race conditions to your code. For example, by not taking a locking when accessing `m_quit`, the notify in `Stop()` might not have any effect, because in `Monitor()`, you first read `m_quit`, which might still be `false`, then `Stop()` could set `m_quit` to `true` and notify `m_cv`, but only then `Monitor()` takes a lock and calls `m_cv.wait_until(...)`, however that latter call will not see notifications that came before it, so it will wait for the full job interval, and if that is a large duration, it will seem like your program is hanging.

Comment: @Sliepen Thanks for your review! I like the idea of hiding the Job implementation within the JobManager. I was a bit confused when you said that std::list does not require the objects it holds to be copyable. However, I realize now the the emplace_back method will construct the object in place, so the Job itself does not need to be coypable or wrapped in a shared_ptr (as you said). I'm going to do a rewrite taking your input, would you care to see an updated version?

Comment: @Sliepen How much of the improper locking can be solved by using atomic bools? How exactly do I guarantee that the Stop() method would synchronize m_quit correctly with Monitor()? Right now, I have the Monitor() loop locking and checking m_quit before and after the m_cv.wait_until(...) section. Does it even make sense to have an m_waiting bool?

Comment: We always like to see people incorporate our answers in their code! If you want the new version to be reviewed, just create a new review question here on Code Review, and then you can add a link here to the new question. As for atomic bools, that doesn't really help here. Everything that is used together, be that the bools or the condition variable used to signal changes in those bools, should be guarded by the same mutex. The `m_waiting` bool is indeed redundant,

Comment: Also, since you are new, please read [what should you do when someone answers your question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I have created a new question holding a revised version of the posted code. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/277786/a-c-job-manager-class-rev-1

Answer (score 1):

I don't have time for a full review at the moment, but just glancing at it, one thing jumped out at me about `JobManager`: you don't seem to have really made up your mind whether you want it to support derivation or not.

On one hand, it has some `protected` members, which generally only make sense if something is going to derive from it.

On the other hand, it contains no virtual functions, so there's nothing for a derived class to override. Its destructor isn't virtual either, which generally means it shouldn't be used as a base class.

There are a few cases (such as private inheritance) where a class can have a non-virtual destructor, and still be used as a base class. But even in a case like this, you generally need at least one virtual function to override before inheritance makes sense. Otherwise, you should probably just aggregate an instance of the class into whatever else you're creating.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I believe I'm wanting nothing to derive from this class. Does it make sense to just change the protected members to private, or should I also mark the class as "final"?  I'm going to go ahead and update my code snippet to change both.

Comment: I've also removed the ThreadLoop from the JobManager class and I realize now that it's not needed. The Start and Stop member methods directly start and stop each job.

Comment: `private` certainly makes sense. `final`...might also, but I'm somewhat uncertain. It's generally considered bad form to edit code here in a way that invalidates existing answers. If you want a review of updated code, that generally belongs in a new question (which should probably link back to this one).

Comment: That makes sense to me, I'll do that for any future posts.